# SQL server 2012, combined primary key needs to be unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hello i have a question i assume mainly about SQL server functionality. Im building a test database and i have stumbled a problem when i try to insert data into my tables.

picture 1 shows the error message i get when trying to add rows.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW3C2.png

Picture 2 shows all relations in the database
//i.stack.imgur.com/7BhHa.png

picture 3 shows the table i am currently trying to update 
//i.stack.imgur.com/3JqtA.png

In the table i have a combined primary key ("SDat" and "Kurs") The error message i get implyes that primary key must be uniqe, but what dont understand is since i have a third column "Elev" which makes the row uniqe, why wont SQL server me insert this row to table? I have tried making the same database in Acess and it works so i assume problem is something in SQL server

Regards Robert

Comment: can you not add the field 'Elev' into your primary key definition?

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Primary Key by definition means the value must be unique.  So if you have a combined primary key on 2 fields, then that value on those 2 fields needs to be unique meaning it can only have 1 row.  If you need to enforce unique values on the combination of 3 fields (SDat, Kurs, and Elev) then your PK needs to include all 3 fields.

If you really need to enforce a unique constraint across alot of fields in a table, I wouldn't use a PK to enforce that, but instead use a `UNIQUE` constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD CONSTRAINT constraintname UNIQUE (column1, ..., columnn)
```

Then you can create a different column for your Primary Key so that as you add columns and need to require those additional columns be unique, you don't have to edit your PK and rebuild your table.